# Apache+fcgi to create SSE Application - How to tell Apache to forward all requests immediately to the fcgi module?

Tags: c++, apache, c++11, fastcgi, mod-fcgid

I've written a fcig module in C++ using fcgipp. The module is able to queue up requests and, if a request with some special settings comes in (POST data, GET data, URL, etc), trigger all requests and send them ServerSentEvent-formatted data.

Unfortunately, Apache does queue up my requests (verified with Iceweasel + w3m for calling the localhost/trigger), so there only lives one request in my queue at a time, until this request timeouts. Just after the first request timeouted, the trigger request gets into my fcgi app, but well.. there's no request to trigger left, then.

My Settings for Apache differ from the standard configuration by these lines:

```
# My cpp application lives there
FcgidWrapper "/var/www/tfcgi_test"
FcgidMaxProcesses 1
FcgidMaxProcessesPerClass 1
FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 50
FcgidProcessLifeTime 0
```

Which settings do I need, so apache sends the requests to the fcgi module as soon as they come in?

Answer (score 0):

Because you've set `FcgidMaxProcesses` to 1, only one instance of your application can be active at a time. As a result, if an instance of your application is already active and servicing a request, any other incoming requests will have to wait until the first one finishes.

Set `FcgidMaxProcesses` (and `FcgidMaxProcessesPerClass`) to a higher value to handle multiple simultaneous requests.